# "Send e-mail to" with Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook

Tags: c#, asp.net, webforms, outlook

in my development machine I developed a method that work without problem. Its a simple button and when I clicked it open an outlook email with a email adress and some content But when I sent the code to the production enviroment... all users are getting an error on page_load of the page where the following method are set.

```
protected void btnSendEmail_Click(object sender, ImageClickEventArgs e)
{
    //...
    Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.Application oApp = new Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.Application();
    Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook._MailItem oMailItem = (Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook._MailItem)oApp.CreateItem(Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.OlItemType.olMailItem);
    string name = someDataTable.Rows[0]["NAME"].ToString();
    string url = HttpContext.Current.Request.Url.AbsoluteUri;
    oMailItem.To = someEmail@Gmail.com;
    oMailItem.Body = string.Format("hi {0}, \n \n [Insert the content mail here.] \n \n {1} ", name, url);
    oMailItem.Subject = "Some Title";
    oMailItem.Display(false);
}
```

Comment: What's the error, my crystal ball is on the blink at the moment.

Answer (score 1):

The Microsoft Office Interop assemblies would open Outlook on the server (assuming Outlook is installed on the server), not on the client. Is that your intention?

The Microsoft Office Interop assemblies are not supported on the server side. See [KB Article](https://support.microsoft.com/kb/257757).

I suggest you switch to some other technology. If you're just trying to have the server send an email, try taking at look at the System.Net.Mail namespace. See [How To Send An Email With C#.](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/a75533eb-131b-4ff3-a3b2-b6df87c25cc8/how-do-i-send-mail-using-c?forum=netfxnetcom)

If your intention is to launch an Outlook new email window on the client side, it's easy to accomplish that with a simple HTML anchor link. See [Sending HTML in mailto anchor tag](http://www.webdevelopersnotes.com/tips/html/html_mailto_attribute_html_tips.php3).